# Boost Locking with try_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

I'm trying to solve a locking problem with Boost 1.46.1 - I tried a few things but I am not happy - and therefore would love to hear inputs from the clean cut.

Thread A:

- Must always wait and obtain a lock for a critical data section
- Updates some critical data
- Manual unlock (or scoped)

Thread B
- Must never block (try_lock?)
- Reads data from the mentioned critical section if lock obtained

I'm unsure if I need a shared_lock or if I can solve this otherwise.

EDIT, my code looks like:
Thread A:

```
{
 // Critical section
 boost::mutex::scoped_lock  lock( _mutex) ;
}
```

Thread B:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex, boost::try_to_lock);
if( lock ) {

}
```

But I haven't been able to log a failed try_lock - so I wonder if it really works.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: Every lock as a "try"-type function that you can use to avoid blocking.

Comment: So what's the problem with using `try_lock`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me it seems like it's working, except that scoped locks are not FIFO, i.e., first thread to request the lock, is not the first thread to get the lock. I used the following code for testing:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

boost::mutex mutex;

void threadA()
{
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; )
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Locked by A\n");
            usleep(100000);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unlocked by A\n");
            i--;
        }
    }
}

void threadB()
{
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; )
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex, boost::try_to_lock);
        if (lock)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Locked by B\n");
            usleep(100000);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unlocked by B\n");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Lock failed in B\n");
            usleep(100000);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    boost::thread a(threadA);
    boost::thread b(threadB);
    a.join();
    b.join();
}
```

And I get the output

```
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Lock failed in B
Lock failed in B
Unlocked by A
Locked by A
Unlocked by A
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
Locked by B
Unlocked by B
```